# Is there any computation of $K^0(X)$ and $K_0(X)$ for a singular curve $X$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $X$ be a projective curve over an algebraic closed field $k$ which characteristic zero. Define $K^0(X)$ as the Grothendieck group of the derived category $Perf(X)$ and $K_0(X)$ as the Grothendieck group of the derived category $D^b_{\text{coh}}(X)$.

If $X$ is a smooth curve, then it is well-known that 
$$
K^0(X)\cong K_0(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus Pic(X).
$$

Now if $X$ is singular, do we have any explicit computations on $K^0(X)$ and $K_0(X)$?

Comment: Look at Weibel's *K-Book*, Ch. II, Ex. 8.2.  For $K^0(X)$, the same formula holds, it's ${\Bbb Z}$ plus Pic.  For $K_0$, you can compute via the normalization.  (Neither characteristic zero nor projective are necessary.)

Comment: @DaveAnderson Thank you very much! By the way where can I find the relation between the $K_0$ of $X$ and the normalization of $X$? Is it also in Weibel's book?